# Boundedness of relative risk aversion function

Tags: calculus

Let $f\colon [0,\infty)\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly increasing and strictly concave function. Let $$RRA_f(x)=-\frac{xf''(x)}{f'(x)}.$$
Is it possible that $RRA_f$ isn't bounded?

Comment: It is possible to be unbounded.  See answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x) = 1-e^{-x}$ on $[0,\infty)$.

We have

$$f'(x) = e^{-x}>0, \\ f''(x)=-e^{-x}<0.$$

So $f$ is strictly increasing and strictly concave.

However,

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}-\frac{xf''(x)}{f'(x)}= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}-\frac{-xe^{-x}}{e^{-x}}= \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}x= \infty$$

So in this case, $RRA$ is unbounded on $[0,\infty)$.